# Display H1 and Span underneath each other and center aligned in Angular Material Mat-Grid

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following code:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <h1 class="title">Heading</h1>
    <span class="spanText">Span Text</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>

  <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

And the `css`

```
.title {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.spanText {
  display: block;
}
```

I am trying to display the H1 and the Span underneath each other (H1 above and span below) while keeping them center aligned in the `mat-grid`. But the `display: block` does nothing and doesn't change the position of the `span`. Right now, they're being displayed in-line, right next to each other.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the `<h1>` and the `<span>` in an extra `div` like so:

```
<mat-grid-tile>
  <div>
    <h1 class="title">Heading</h1>
    <span class="spanText">Span Text</span>
  </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

and remove the `display: block` ;)